# while i am extract the character from the word at that time why confidence values of the similar character in words are different?

Tags: c++, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

see , i am extract the word from the image and check confidence level of the each character from that word . each time i am getting different confidence level even it is belong to same word.

below example.

01.01.2012  word in which 3 times 0 char encounter and 3 times i am getting the different confidence level.

Here is the input image and i am getting output as text file u can seen below. my requirement is such a way that only number data i want. so that in image ,if any word contain number between 0 to 9 then i store the particular word and corresponding char and confidence value into the file. as u can see below .like that i make individual file from 0 to 9. for our reference purpose i shown 0 char file.

[image]

```
WORD          CHAR      confidence
7/11/2014       0       94.3153
01.01.2012      0       91.9117
01.01.2012      0       95.059
01.01.2012      0       95.1877
31.12.2012      0       92.1003
05.07.2013      0       94.4376
05.07.2013      0       97.3389
05.07.2013      0       92.4576
2012            0       94.0608
2012            0       93.1969
31.12.2012      0       93.8993
31.12.2011      0       94.513
606             0       93.5746
405             0       93.6727
109.821         0       96.2786
331.028         0       96.1837
109.506;        0       93.1421
109.506;        0       93.7133
110.427         0       93.7141
946.130         0       96.3438
200.274         0       95.7532
200.274         0       94.8678
10.553.331      0       96.3162
10.186.341      0       94.15
63.401          0       94.6042
346.350         0       96.2305
343.044         0       95.9801
346.350;        0       93.5741
343.044         0       93.8484
284.506         0       94.6761
0               0       95.9303
420             0       94.0067
0               0       93.2645
7.355.042       0       95.9187
9.108           0       96.3331
10.             0       93.9019
12.042          0       97.3823
294.704         0       93.4084
4.350           0       96.0915
0               0       95.4884
20.559.209      0       95.4821
20.559.209      0       94.1849
19.207.660      0       95.9933
19.207.660      0       95.1577
31.12.2012      0       92.7785
31.12.2011      0       94.6773
14.054          0       95.3734
44.706          0       93.6371
58.760          0       97.2008
4.111.720       0       94.4336
2.873.806       0       95.8218
11.083.608      0       96.1708
11.083.608      0       94.3456
10.721.302      0       93.3877
10.721.302      0       94.978
5.045.424       0       95.424
4.242.083       0       95.424
```

can anybody tell me how the confidence level work behind the seen?

```
#include "./include/header.h"
#include "./include/enum.h"

class RECT
{
public:
    int col;
    int row;
    int width;
    int height;
    char *ocrResult;
};


class OCR
{
public:
    int *g_pixelBuffer;
    int *g_pixelBufferForWord;
    int *g_histogram;
    int  g_Id;

    int initialize (const int row, const int col)
    {
        /// find the size of the image
        int size = row * col ;

        /// allocate the memory for pixel bufferr
        g_pixelBuffer     = (int *)calloc(size, sizeof(int));

        /// Check for proper allocation
        if(g_pixelBuffer == NULL)      return MemoryNotAllocated;

        g_pixelBufferForWord     = (int *)calloc(size, sizeof(int));

        /// Check for proper allocation
        if(g_pixelBufferForWord == NULL)      return MemoryNotAllocated;

        /// allocating memory for histogram
        g_histogram        = (int *)calloc(size ,sizeof(int));

        /// check proper allocation
        if(g_histogram == NULL)     return MemoryNotAllocated;

        g_Id  = 1;


        return Success;
    }

    vector<RECT >  processImage(Mat &image, int size, int ,int );

    void dumpIntoFile(vector<RECT > &rectBuffer, char *outputFile);


    void release()
    {
        // release pixel_buffer memory
        free(g_pixelBuffer);
        free(g_pixelBufferForWord);
        /// release histogram memory
        free(g_histogram);

    }

};

ofstream myfile1("1.txt");
ofstream myfile2("2.txt");
ofstream myfile3("3.txt");
ofstream myfile4("4.txt");
ofstream myfile5("5.txt");
ofstream myfile6("6.txt");
ofstream myfile7("7.txt");
ofstream myfile8("8.txt");
ofstream myfile9("9.txt");
ofstream myfile0("0.txt");


void displayBoundingBox(int staCol, int staRow, int edCol, int edRow
        , int *PixelBufferForWord, int);

void dumpNumberConfidenceIntoFile(char *word, float confi, char *Char);

void getWordDataFromLine(const int *PixelBuffer, int *PixelBufferForWord, RECT &rectLine,
        int mainImageCol, vector <RECT> &rectBuffer);

void  dumpDataIntoFile (int  *, int collenth, int strow, int stcol,
        int enrow, int encols, char *output);

//void dumpIntoFile(vector<RECT > &rectBuffer, char *outputFile);

void GetBinaryImage(Mat &image ,OCR *,const int size);

void  getBinaryImage(OCR *,int size);


void getCharDataFromWord(const int *PixelBuffer,int *PixelBufferForChar, int startColWord ,int startRowWord,
        int endColWord, int endRowWord, RECT &rectLine,
        int mainImageCol,vector<RECT > &rectBuffer, RECT &rectWord);

int main(int argc ,char **argv)

{
    int rs = Success;

    Mat image = imread(argv[1]);//read the image

    if(!image.data){
        cout << "can't able to read the image" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int rows = image.rows;// get the rows

    int cols = image.cols;// get the col

    int size = rows * cols;// get the size

    OCR ocr;



    /// Allocate or initialize memory
    rs = ocr.initialize (rows, cols);

    /// check proper allocation
    if(rs == MemoryNotAllocated)    return rs;

    myfile1 << "WORD" << '\t' << '\t' <<  "CHAR" << '\t' << '\t' <<  "confidence" << endl;
    myfile2 << "WORD" << '\t' << '\t' <<  "CHAR" << '\t' << '\t' << "confidence" << endl;
    myfile3 << "WORD" << '\t' << '\t' <<  "CHAR" << '\t' << '\t' << "confidence" << endl;
    myfile4 << "WORD" << '\t' << '\t' << "CHAR" << '\t' << '\t' << "confidence" << endl;
    myfile5 << "WORD" << '\t' << '\t' <<  "CHAR" << '\t' << '\t' <<"confidence" << endl;
    myfile6 << "WORD" << '\t' << '\t' <<  "CHAR" << '\t' << '\t' <<"confidence" << endl;
    myfile7 << "WORD" << '\t' << '\t' <<  "CHAR" << '\t' << '\t' <<"confidence" << endl;
    myfile8 << "WORD" << '\t' << '\t' << "CHAR" << '\t' << '\t' << "confidence" << endl;
    myfile9 << "WORD" << '\t' << '\t' << "CHAR" << '\t' << '\t' << "confidence" << endl;
    myfile0 << "WORD" << '\t' << '\t' << "CHAR" << '\t' << '\t' << "confidence" << endl;



    vector <RECT> rectBuffer = ocr.processImage(image, size, rows, cols);

    ocr.dumpIntoFile(rectBuffer, argv[2] );

    //dumpDataIntoFile (ocr.g_pixelBufferForWord, cols, 0, 0, rows - 1, cols - 1, ( char *)"test123456.pbm");


    ocr.release();

}

vector <RECT> OCR ::processImage(Mat &image, int size, int rows, int cols)
{

    GetBinaryImage (image, this, size);// convert the image into the binary

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        g_pixelBufferForWord[i] = g_pixelBuffer[i];
    }



    //  dumpDataIntoFile (this, w, 0, 0, h - 1, w - 1, (char *)"test123.pbm");


    tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;

    if (tess.Init("/usr/share/tesseract/tessdata", "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    tess.SetImage((unsigned char*)g_pixelBuffer, cols, rows, sizeof(int)
            ,sizeof(int) * cols);

    tess.Recognize(0);

    tesseract::ResultIterator *riLine = tess.GetIterator();

    tesseract::PageIteratorLevel levelLine = tesseract:: RIL_TEXTLINE;


    RECT rectLine;
    vector <RECT> rectBuffer;

    if(riLine!=0)
    {
        do {
            char *Line = riLine->GetUTF8Text(levelLine);

            if(Line != NULL)
            {
                int startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow;

                riLine->BoundingBox(levelLine, &startCol, &startRow, &endCol, &endRow);

                int width  = endCol - startCol + 1;
                int height = endRow - startRow + 1;

                rectLine.col    = startCol;
                rectLine.row    = startRow;
                rectLine.width  = width;
                rectLine.height = height;

                int length = strlen(Line) + 1;

                rectLine.ocrResult = (char *)calloc( length, sizeof(char));

                if(rectLine.ocrResult == NULL){
                    cout << "rectLine.ocrResult is not allocate"<< endl;
                    exit(1);
                }

                strcpy(rectLine.ocrResult, Line);

                rectBuffer.push_back(rectLine);

                getWordDataFromLine(g_pixelBuffer,g_pixelBufferForWord, rectLine,cols, rectBuffer);

                free(Line);
                //delete Line;
            }

        } while (riLine->Next(levelLine));

    }

    //dumpIntoFile(rectBuffer, argv[2]);

    tess.End();
    delete riLine;

    return rectBuffer;

}

void getWordDataFromLine(const int *PixelBuffer,  int *PixelBufferForWord, RECT &rectLine,
        int mainImageCol, vector <RECT> &rectBuffer)
{
    int index;

    int *SubImageBuffer = (int *)calloc(rectLine.width  * rectLine.height, sizeof(int));

    if(!SubImageBuffer){

        cout << "SubImageBuffer not allocate" << endl;
    }

    int i = 0;

    for(int r = rectLine.row ; r < rectLine.row + rectLine.height; r++)
    {
        for(int c = rectLine.col ; c < rectLine.col + rectLine.width; c++)
        {
            index = r * mainImageCol + c;

            SubImageBuffer[i++] = PixelBuffer[index];
        }
    }
    //dumpDataIntoFile (SubImageBuffer, w, 0, 0, h - 1, w - 1, (char *)"test123.pbm");

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI tessWord;

    if (tessWord.Init("/usr/share/tesseract/tessdata", "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    tessWord.SetImage((unsigned char*)SubImageBuffer, rectLine.width,
            rectLine.height, sizeof(int) ,sizeof(int) * rectLine.width);

    tessWord.Recognize(0);

    tesseract::ResultIterator *riWord = tessWord.GetIterator();

    tesseract::PageIteratorLevel levelWord = tesseract:: RIL_WORD;

    RECT rectWord;

    if(riWord!=0)
    {
        do {
            char *Word = riWord->GetUTF8Text(levelWord);

            if(Word != NULL)
            {
                int startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow;
                int staCol = 0, staRow = 0, edCol = 0, edRow = 0;
                riWord->BoundingBox(levelWord, &startCol, &startRow, &endCol, &endRow);

                staCol =  startCol;
                staRow =  startRow;
                edCol  =   endCol;
                edRow  =   endRow;

                staCol += rectLine.col;
                staRow += rectLine.row;
                edRow  += rectLine.row;
                edCol  += rectLine.col;



                rectWord.col    = staCol;
                rectWord.row    = staRow;
                rectWord.width  = edCol - staCol + 1;
                rectWord.height = edRow - staRow + 1;

                int length = strlen(Word) + 1;

                rectWord.ocrResult = (char *)calloc( length, sizeof(char));

                if(rectWord.ocrResult == NULL){
                    cout << "rectWord.ocrResult is not allocate"<< endl;
                    exit(1);
                }

                strcpy(rectWord.ocrResult, Word);

                rectBuffer.push_back(rectWord);

                //displayBoundingBox(staCol, staRow, edCol, edRow ,PixelBufferForWord, mainImageCol);

                getCharDataFromWord(SubImageBuffer, PixelBufferForWord, startCol, startRow ,endCol ,endRow,
                        rectLine,mainImageCol, rectBuffer, rectWord);
                //delete Word;

                free(Word);
            }
        }while (riWord->Next(levelWord));
    }
    delete riWord;
    tessWord.End();
    free(SubImageBuffer);
}


void getCharDataFromWord(const int *PixelBuffer,int *PixelBufferForChar, int startColWord ,int startRowWord,
        int endColWord, int endRowWord, RECT &rectLine,
        int mainImageCol,vector<RECT > &rectBuffer, RECT &rectWord)
{
    int index;

    int width  = endColWord - startColWord + 1;
    int height = endRowWord - startRowWord + 1;

    int *SubImageBufferForChar = (int *)calloc(width * height, sizeof(int));

    if(!SubImageBufferForChar){

        cout << "SubImageBuffer not read" << endl;
    }

    int i = 0;

    for(int r = startRowWord ; r <= endRowWord; r++)
    {
        for(int c = startColWord; c <= endColWord; c++)
        {
            index = r * rectLine.width + c;

            SubImageBufferForChar[i++] = PixelBuffer[index];

        }
    }

    //dumpDataIntoFile (SubImageBufferForChar, width, 0, 0, height - 1, width - 1, (char *)"test123.pbm");

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI tessChar;


    if (tessChar.Init("/usr/share/tesseract/tessdata", "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    tessChar.SetImage((unsigned char*)SubImageBufferForChar, width,
            height, sizeof(int) ,sizeof(int) * width);

    tessChar.Recognize(0);

    tesseract::ResultIterator *riChar = tessChar.GetIterator();

    tesseract::PageIteratorLevel levelChar = tesseract:: RIL_SYMBOL;

    RECT rectChar;



    if(riChar!=0)
    {
        do {
            char *Char = riChar->GetUTF8Text(levelChar);

            if(Char != NULL)
            {
                float conf = riChar->Confidence(levelChar);

                int startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow;

                riChar->BoundingBox(levelChar, &startCol, &startRow, &endCol, &endRow);

                startCol += rectWord.col;
                startRow += rectWord.row;
                endRow   += rectWord.row;
                endCol   += rectWord.col;

                rectChar.col    = startCol;
                rectChar.row    = startRow;
                rectChar.width  = endCol - startCol + 1;
                rectChar.height = endRow - startRow + 1;

                int length = strlen(Char) + 1;

                rectChar.ocrResult = (char *)calloc( length, sizeof(char));

                if(rectChar.ocrResult == NULL){
                    cout << "rectChar.ocrResult is not allocate"<< endl;
                    exit(1);
                }
                strcpy(rectChar.ocrResult, Char);

                rectBuffer.push_back(rectChar);


                dumpNumberConfidenceIntoFile(rectWord.ocrResult, conf, Char);

                //displayBoundingBox(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow ,PixelBufferForChar, mainImageCol);

                //delete Char;
                free(Char);


            }
        } while (riChar->Next(levelChar));
    }


    delete riChar;
    tessChar.End();
    free(SubImageBufferForChar);

}

void dumpNumberConfidenceIntoFile(char *word, float confi, char *Char)
{

    if(Char[0] >= '0' && Char[0] <= '9')
    {
        if(Char[0] == '0'){
            myfile0 << word << '\t' << '\t' << Char << '\t'  << '\t' << confi << endl;
        }
        else if(Char[0] == '1'){
            myfile1 << word << '\t' << '\t' << Char << '\t' << '\t' <<confi << endl;
        }
        else if(Char[0] == '2'){
            myfile2 << word << '\t' << '\t' << Char << '\t' << '\t' << confi << endl;
        }
        else if(Char[0] == '3'){
            myfile3 << word << '\t' << '\t' << Char << '\t' << '\t' << confi << endl;
        }
        else if(Char[0] == '4'){
            myfile4 << word << '\t' << '\t' << Char << '\t' << '\t'  <<confi << endl;
        }
        else if(Char[0] == '5'){
            myfile5 << word << '\t' << '\t' << Char << '\t' << '\t' <<confi << endl;
        }
        else if(Char[0] == '6'){
            myfile6 << word << '\t' << '\t' << Char << '\t' <<  '\t' << confi << endl;
        }
        else if(Char[0] == '7'){
            myfile7 << word << '\t' << '\t' << Char << '\t' << '\t'  << confi << endl;
        }
        else if(Char[0] == '8'){
            myfile8 << word << '\t' << '\t' << Char << '\t' <<  '\t' << confi << endl;
        }
        else if(Char[0] == '9'){
            myfile9 << word << '\t' << '\t' << Char << '\t' <<  '\t' << confi << endl;
        }

    }

}



void OCR ::dumpIntoFile(vector<RECT > &rectBuffer, char *outputFile)
{
    ofstream myfile(outputFile);

    myfile << "ID" << '\t' << "CORD_X" << '\t'  << "CORD_Y" << '\t' <<
            "CORD_W" << '\t' << "CORD_H" << '\t' << "STRING" << endl;

    for(auto it = rectBuffer.begin(); it != rectBuffer.end(); it++)
    {
        myfile << g_Id++ << '\t' << it->col  << '\t' << it->row << '\t' <<
                it->width << '\t' << it->height << '\t';


        int length = strlen(it->ocrResult);

        //cout << "in the string (" << length << ") ::" << endl;
        for(int  j = 0; j < length && it->ocrResult[j] != '\n'; j++)
        {
            myfile << it->ocrResult[j];
        }
        myfile << endl;


    }

}
void  getBinaryImage(OCR *ocr, int size)
{
    long long int total = size;
    long long int sum   = 0;
    long long int q1    = 0;
    long long int q2    = 0;
    float SUM           = 0;
    float u1            = 0;
    float u2            = 0;
    float result        = 0;
    float var_max       = 0;
    int threshold       = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 256 ;i++)
        sum = sum + i * ocr->g_histogram[i];

    for(int t = 0; t < 256 ; t++)
    {
        q1 = q1 + ocr->g_histogram[t];
        q2 = total - q1;

        SUM  = SUM + t * ocr->g_histogram[t];

        u1 = SUM / q1 ;

        u2 = (sum - SUM) / q2;

        result =  q1 * q2 * (u1 - u2) * (u1 - u2);

        if(result > var_max)
        {
            threshold = t;
            var_max   = result;
        }


    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        if(ocr->g_pixelBuffer[i] > threshold){
            ocr->g_pixelBuffer[i] = 0;
        }else{
            ocr->g_pixelBuffer[i] = 1;
        }
    }
}
void GetBinaryImage(Mat &image ,OCR *ocr ,const int size)
{

    Mat  channel[3];// convert the image first into Binary image

    split(image,channel); // spilt the image

    uchar *Blue  = channel[0].data; // get the blue value
    uchar *Green = channel[1].data; // get the green value
    uchar *Red   = channel[2].data; // get the red value

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        ocr->g_pixelBuffer[i]=  ((Red[i]) + (Green[i]) + (Blue[i])) / 3;// get the gray data
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ocr->g_histogram[ocr->g_pixelBuffer[i]]++;// create the histogram for the OTSU thersholding
    }


    getBinaryImage (ocr,size);// got the binary image
}

void  dumpDataIntoFile (int *pixelBuffer, int collenth, int strow, int stcol,
        int enrow, int encols, char *output)
{
    int i, j, index;

    int cols = encols - stcol + 1;
    int rows = enrow  - strow + 1;

    ofstream myfile(output);

    myfile <<  "P1" << endl;

    myfile <<  cols  <<  " " << rows << endl;

    for(i = strow; i <= enrow ; i++ ) {
        for(j = stcol; j <= encols; j++ ) {

            index = i * collenth + j;

            if(pixelBuffer[index] != 0) {
                myfile << "1" << " ";
            } else {
                myfile << "0" << " ";
            }
        }
        myfile << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
}


void displayBoundingBox(int staCol, int staRow, int edCol, int edRow , int *PixelBufferForWord,int mainImageCol)
{
    int index;

    for(int i = staRow; i < edRow ; i++ ) {

        index = i * mainImageCol + staCol ;//height left
        PixelBufferForWord[index] = 255;

        index = i * mainImageCol + edCol ;// height right
        PixelBufferForWord[index] = 255;
    }

    for(int j = staCol; j < edCol; j++ ) {

        index = staRow * mainImageCol + j;//top
        PixelBufferForWord[index] = 255;

        index = edRow  * mainImageCol + j;// bottom
        PixelBufferForWord[index] = 255;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your code. Also, make choice: C or C++, not both in the tags.

Comment: Because in, say `01.01.2012` the OCR code is looking at three different occurrences of the `0` images. So the confidence of each is high but not exactly the same, because the images are not exactly the same.

Comment: We need to see more confidential data to make a call.

Comment: ...such as how much cash in the vault today.

Comment: now you  can  my code,Barmar. you get some better idea. actually , i am extract first line then  after extract the word from that line and then after extract the char from that word. at last i am comparing char is present between o to 9 or not . if it between them then i am storing into the file. at that the end i am create the file in which store first line data then after word data belong to that line and then after char data belong to that word.

Comment: i think image is same only  and word is also same . then why confidence is different Weather Vane?

Comment: Because it's an OCR scan of a printed image. Even if the dots of the printed image are identical, they would have to align perfectly with the scanner's resolution, which will probably have a different pitch, be at a slightly different angle etc. Look at a printer output through a magnifying glass and you will see the imperfections anyway. If you compare 3 donuts against the ideal donut, they will all vary slightly.

Comment: ok ,thanks weather Vane

Comment: i have one more question . how the confidence algorithm work ? can you tell me  what is the logic of calculation of the confidence value ? Weather vane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q:- How is confidence level calculated.

Confidence algorithm works on the distance of the recognized characters from the available characters. 
This "linguistic analysis" section on this link provides the answer you are looking for :- https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/docs/blob/master/tesseracticdar2007.pdf